# Basic question on cohomology ring

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

To show

> (1) $S^2\vee S^1\vee S^1$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^1\times S^1$
>
> (2) $S^1\vee S^2\vee S^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^1\times S^2$

I use the same method:

For (1) the product of the two generators of $H^1(S^2\vee S^1\vee S^1)$ is $0$ while the product of the two generators of $H^1(S^1\times S^1)$ is the generator of $H^2(S^1\times S^1)$.

For (2) the product of the generator of $H^1(S^1\vee S^2\vee S^3)$ and the generator of $H^2(S^1\vee S^2\vee S^3)$ is $0$ while the product of the generator of $H^1(S^1\times S^2)$ and the generator of $H^2(S^1\times S^2)$ is the generator of $H^3(S^1\times S^2)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Nitpick: maps are homotopic. Spaces are *homotopy-equivalent.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've said is correct, though of course it requires proof.